# jQuery Flip front to 2 different backsides

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, authentication, flip

I am having trouble getting a certain feature to work.

As you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/y5jn4tco/1/

`<div> CHECK CODE AT JSFIDDLE</div>`

I am using the flip jquery plugin which made a flip, where you choose a category, and then gets sent to a certain login screen. My issue is, that I want the bottom one to flip to another backside. I have tried altering the jquery plugin, but without luck. Is there anyone who knows how I could make this work?

So the pink one goes to the pink login, and the blue one goes to the blue login.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Wrap The Student And Company Into Main Div I Also rotate Main Div#centerMain Front And Back
Then If You Clicked In Student Then Company Form Hide And Student Display In Div#centerMain

If You Clicked In Company Then Student Form Hide And Company Display In Div#centerMain

And I Change #back To .back

```
I Solve This In Fork Try This
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ehab6sqs/

Comment: You Welcome Sir If Any Other Problem In Your Code Post It

Answer (score 1):

You Need To Wrap Your Div int Another Div Then Flip Back Div To Front And Front To back 
1 div Is A
2 div is B 
A-> 1
Student
2 Company 
B -> 2 Buttons
IF Click In btn1 Then Hide company and Flip

```
 $("#centerModuleCompany").css('display','none');
    $("#centerModuleStudent").css('display','block');
```

IF Click In btn1 Then Hide Student and Flip

```
  $("#centerModuleCompany").css('display','block');
        $("#centerModuleStudent").css('display','none');
```

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes to your `document.ready` function as below:

Here is the **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/y5jn4tco/3/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cards").flip({
        trigger: 'manual'
    });

    $("#loginStudent").click(function(){

    $(".cards").flip(true);      
        $("#centerModuleStudent").css('display','block');
        $("#centerModuleCompany").css('display','none');

    });
    $("#loginCompany").click(function(){

       $(".cards").flip(true);        
        $("#centerModuleCompany").css('display','block');
        $("#centerModuleStudent").css('display','none');

    });

    $("#back1,#back2").click(function(){
        $(".cards").flip(false);

    });
});
```

I noticed that you have same ids for back button which is violating DOM element rules so I've changed it to `back1` and `back2` respectively and I am just hiding the alternative `div` on click of each button and showing the required `div`

Your CSS changes:

```
#back1,#back2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: This almost does the job, the problem is just, if you go to 1 of them, then go back and to the other one, the transition only does a half flip. But thanks for you time!